# Google-chrome installation on oracle linux 7.8 dependency problem

Tags: software-installation, repository, chrome, dependencies, oracle-linux

I'm trying to install `google-chrome` on Oracle Linux 7.8 (updated from 7.1). But it is failing due to `libvulkan.so.1()(64 bit)` dependency requirement. Please help on how to resolve this. I have tried downloading the binaries from pkgs.org for centos7 and installing. But it seems there are too many and that chain is long. I also tried installing Vulkan SDK but that is taking me in a different route. I also tried to download and enable the epel and rpm (free and non-free) repositories. They are enabled in the `yum repolist` command output but still when I try `yum install google-chrome-stable`, it does not resolve. What is the best way to get this working? Thanks, Bala.

Installation response:

```
[root@olx71 Downloads]# yum install google-chrome

Loaded plugins: ulninfo Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-unstable.x86_64 0:83.0.4103.7-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-unstable-83.0.4103.7-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: google-chrome-unstable-83.0.4103.7-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
    Requires: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit) You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this for installing google-chrome-stable 83.0.4103.61 on Oracle Linux 7.8 Slim by enabling the optional repo:

```
yum-config-manager --enable ol7_optional_latest
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had the same issue within OEL 7.0. Surpassed the problem through your solution like a charm! Google Chrome added to the Application menu. But I don't know the reason why it doesn't startup as I clicked on ...

Comment: Glad it helped @BarbarosÖzhan! I was using Chrome headlessly so haven't experienced that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

i have done it right now. You must install all dependecies:

```
yum install liberation-fonts
yum install libXScrnSaver.x86_64 libappindicator.x86_64 libappindicator-gtk3.x86_64
yum install vulkan
```

Now install normally chrome:

```
rpm -ivh google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

My system is :
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)

My enabled repos:

```
subscription-manager repos --list-enabled

ID de repositorio:     rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - RH Common (RPMs)
ID de repositorio:     rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)
ID de repositorio:     rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Software Collections RPMs for Red Hat     Enterprise 
ID de repositorio:     rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.6-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.6 (for RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)
ID de repositorio:     rh-gluster-3-client-for-rhel-7-server-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Storage Native Client for RHEL 7 (RPMs)
ID de repositorio:     rhel-7-server-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)
ID de repositorio:     rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
Nombre de repositorio: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As of 5/14/2021, none of these previous answers work. As this is an ever-changing set of libraries that constantly gets out of date.

Here are the latest set of steps that allow you to get Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

```
yum -y install wget
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/vulkan-1.1.97.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/vulkan-filesystem-1.1.97.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install libX11-devel.x86_64 libXext.x86_64 libwayland-client.x86_64
yum -y install vulkan*
yum -y install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks, these steps worked for me on Linux Redhat.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same error on RHEL 7.8. 
I followed the suggestion

---

yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf

---

And ran again

The error came up but it continued to search a few repos and eventually found it.

============================= 
Dependency resolving was successful thanks to enabling these repositories:
rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rpms
/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64

---

Installed:
  google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:81.0.4044.92-1

Dependency Installed:
  libappindicator-gtk3.x86_64 0:12.10.0-13.el7    libdbusmenu.x86_64 0:16.04.0-4.el7
  libdbusmenu-gtk3.x86_64 0:16.04.0-4.el7         liberation-fonts.noarch 1:1.07.2-16.el7
  liberation-narrow-fonts.noarch 1:1.07.2-16.el7  libindicator-gtk3.x86_64 0:12.10.1-6.el7
  vulkan.x86_64 0:1.1.97.0-1.el7                  vulkan-filesystem.noarch 0:1.1.97.0-1.el7

Complete!

========================================================================

OK the steps above don't work for Oracle Linux 7.8 like I assumed. I downloaded OL 7.8 and played with it a bit. It's pretty easy though. Here's what I did

// get Chrome
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

// Install a few dependencies using yum
   yum install libappindicator-gtk3-12.10.0-13.el7.x86_64
   yum install libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-6.1.el7.x86_64
   yum install liberation-fonts-1.07.2-16.el7.noarch
   yum install liberation-narrow-fonts-1.07.2-16.el7.noarch

// search for then install these 2 packages 
   rpm -ivh vulkan-filesystem-1.1.97.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
   rpm -ivh vulkan-1.1.97.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

// install chrome
   yum -y localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience. I will try out these and update the thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asks about Oracle Linux but wanted to add a RHEL 7.8 Workstation fix.

I took the advice from Pete Nguyen about optional repos and I enabled the `rhel-7-workstation-optional-rpms` repo and then tried `yum update` again and it worked!